# exponential distribution without computation

Tags: probability

a computer room has 3 air-conditioning units A, B & C. for each of the units the time that they will work before they breakdown is exponentially distributed with mean 10 hours. Initially units A and B are switched on and C is kept in reserve to replace whichever of A or B fails first. When there is one air-conditioning unit still working, what is the probability that it is C.

how do i answer this if i weren't to use any computations?

Answer (score 2):

Exponential distributions are memoryless, so the expected time remaining is independent of the time elapsed.  So once one, breaks, you have the remaining one with C, and the expected time for each to last is equal.  So the answer is 50 percent.